# How can I use an if let statement to check if JSON data is present in multiple constants?

Tags: json, swift, uiimageview, alamofire, swifty-json

The foursquare api endpoint I'm hitting requires me to combine a photo prefix, size, and suffix together to create a usable image URL. I am attempting to do this in the "photoURL" constant which currently works.

How can I check to see if the data for all of the pieces of this photoURL is there (using if let) while combining the variables together to set venueImageView from URL using Haneke?

**Here is my code:**

```
func bindData() {
    let ratingSignals = self.dog?["venue"]["ratingSignals"].stringValue

    let photoURLPrefix = self.dog?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["prefix"].stringValue
    let photoURLSuffix = self.dog?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["suffix"].stringValue
    let photoURL = photoURLPrefix! + "original" + photoURLSuffix!
    let venuePhotoURL = NSURL(string: photoURL)

    println("photo url prefix is \(photoURLPrefix)")
    println("photo url suffix is \(photoURLSuffix)")
    println(photoURL)

    self.openUntilLabel.text = self.dog?["venue"]["hours"]["status"].stringValue
    self.addressLabel.text = self.dog?["venue"]["location"]["address"].stringValue
    self.titleLabel.text = self.dog?["venue"]["name"].stringValue
    self.ratingsLabel.text = "Based on \(ratingSignals) ratings"
    self.ratingImageView.image = UIImage(named:"Score8-5")!

    if let photoURL = photoURLPrefix! + "original" + photoURLSuffix!{
        let url = NSURL(string: photoURL)
        venueImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
    }
```

I commented out self.venueImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(venuePhotoURL!) which currently works, but Im worried that if a request doesnt return an image it will crash the app. So I am trying to use an if let to check that the data exists, and then set the imageView inside of this statement.

**The error I am getting:**

"Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type"

**Here is an image of the error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that a GET request will always return a suffix if a prefix is present, I just tested against the prefix and didn't need to "combine" them.

**Here is my solution: dog(above) is now "pin"**

```
if let photoURLPrefix = self.pin?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["prefix"].stringValue {
        let photoURLSuffix = self.pin?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["suffix"].stringValue
        let photoURL = photoURLPrefix + "original" + photoURLSuffix!
        let venuePhotoURL = NSURL(string: photoURL)
        self.venueImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(venuePhotoURL!)
        println("photo url prefix is \(photoURLPrefix)")
        println("photo url suffix is \(photoURLSuffix)")
        println(photoURL)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not run your code but I think your code will crash even if you remove that if condition and if block completely in case of no data is returned.

You should validate your response like this;

```
let photoURLPrefix? = self.dog?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["prefix"] as String?
let photoURLSuffix? = self.dog?["venue"]["featuredPhotos"]["items"][0]["suffix"] as String?
if (photoURLPrefix == nil || photoURLSuffix == nil)
{
    //Do not proceed
    return;
}
```

I don't know if the way you are retrieving data from dog object, is working but the important thing is that optional sign to use.

Comment: that is giving me a "Consecutive statements on a line must be separate by ';'" Im also using SwiftyJSON, hence the .stringValue. I see your logic, but this doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: wouldn't this also require an else statement after the if, to set the value of the imageView if correct data is in fact present?